# phpExcel write long number in cell

Tags: php, phpexcel, number-formatting

While writing the excel file is fine I see that really long numbers are formulas in excel

Example: 8.71129E+12

instead of: 1234567890

How can I change the format during the PHP Excel Creation?

I'm following the [simple example here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '1234567890', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 4):

Either set the value explicitly as a string, or set a number format mask for the cell that forces display of all digits (e.g. '#,##0' 0r '0') rather than default format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it's works for me :

```
$objPHPExcel
   ->getActiveSheet()
   ->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)
   ->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

And Good luck !