# PHPExcel replacing last three numbers

Tags: php, export, phpexcel, xlsx

I am exporting some data to Excel using PHPExcel. Everything is working fine except some strange behavior that the export replaces the last three digits of a number by zeros.

For example I have this number: `876685900060999549`

But when exporting is it like : `876685900060999000`

As you can see only the last three digits are replaced by zeros.
I have already tried to use `setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER )` but unfortunately this didn't work.

Does someone know why only the last three digits are replaced by zeros and how this can be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are too large to be represented as a 32-bit integer in PHP (or in MS Excel) so they are being converted to float with a corresponding loss of precision.

To get round this, you'll need to force them to be treated as string values: you don't show your code, but try using `setCellValueExplicit()` to force the datatype to string

Comment: I didn't think of the number being too large..
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:
[phpExcel write long number in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046157/phpexcel-write-long-number-in-cell)

You could also have a look at the INI setting for precision:
ini_set("precision", "20");